# use vue2.0 and element-ui el-calendar display week and month

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I want to display the calendar like this:

[image]

[image]

and add checked events,how to implement?

Is that components to implements ?
or use el-table components to implement this .
hope answer thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)